# Redux, handling long calculation

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a details page component named FooComponent containing multiple different labels with different amounts of the Foo entity.

I have a button there, which dispatches an action initiating a long-running POST request to API. It can last up to 35-40 seconds as Foo entity will be recalculated using complex calculation strategies. After request succeeds I need to reload Foo data.

From what I see I have two options here:

1. After request is finished, dispatch the fetchFoo action which will get the recalculated Foo from the API. The thing here is that during the calculation I can move to another page so I won't need this data to be fetched again at all.
2. After request is finished, I dispatch the action, which marks Foo with "invalidate" flag. So in case if I'm still staying at FooComponent, in componentWillReceiveProps I get this flag and reload Foo data.
   I went with this approach though it looks too verbose.

What would you advice? Are the some best practices for this kind of behavior?